# Could not find add method: AddFieldReaderByFieldName while indexing by field name

Tags: indexing

**Sitecore** : 9.1

**What I am doing**: I am trying to index few Rich text fields with HTML tags.
So, we went for, as mentioned by https://learnsitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2016/05/30/sitecore-include-html-tags-in-indexes-for-rich-text-field/

**What is the issue**: But we are getting the error `Could not find add method: AddFieldReaderByFieldName`

**Edit**: Segment with parent:

```
   <defaultSolrIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
      <initializeOnAdd>false</initializeOnAdd>
<fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrFieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">

        <typeMatches hint="raw:AddTypeMatch">
          <typeMatch typeName="guidCollection"     type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Guid]"     fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm"  multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
          <typeMatch typeName="textCollection"     type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"   fieldNameFormat="{0}_txm" multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
          <typeMatch typeName="stringCollection"   type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"   fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm"  multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
          <typeMatch typeName="intCollection"      type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]"    fieldNameFormat="{0}_im"  multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
          <typeMatch typeName="guid"               type="System.Guid"                                        fieldNameFormat="{0}_s"                                         settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
          <typeMatch typeName="id"                 type="Sitecore.Data.ID, Sitecore.Kernel"                  fieldNameFormat="{0}_s"                                         settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
          <typeMatch typeName="shortid"            type="Sitecore.Data.ShortID, Sitecore.Kernel"             fieldNameFormat="{0}_s"                                         settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
          <typeMatch typeName="string"             type="System.String"                                      fieldNameFormat="{0}_s"                                         settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
          <typeMatch typeName="text"               type="System.String"                                      fieldNameFormat="{0}_t"   cultureFormat="_{1}"                  settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
          <typeMatch typeName="int"                type="System.Int32"                                       fieldNameFormat="{0}_tl"                                        settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
          <typeMatch typeName="bool"               type="System.Boolean"                                     fieldNameFormat="{0}_b"                                         settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
          <typeMatch typeName="datetime"           type="System.DateTime"                                    fieldNameFormat="{0}_tdt" format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.FFF'Z'" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
          <typeMatch typeName="long"               type="System.Int64"                                       fieldNameFormat="{0}_tl"                                        settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
          <typeMatch typeName="float"              type="System.Single"                                      fieldNameFormat="{0}_tf"                                        settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
          <typeMatch typeName="double"             type="System.Double"                                      fieldNameFormat="{0}_td"                                        settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
          <typeMatch typeName="stringArray"        type="System.String[]"                                    fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm"  multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
          <typeMatch typeName="intArray"           type="System.Int32[]"                                     fieldNameFormat="{0}_im"  multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
          <typeMatch typeName="datetimeArray"      type="System.DateTime[]"                                  fieldNameFormat="{0}_dtm" multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
          <typeMatch typeName="datetimeCollection" type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime]" fieldNameFormat="{0}_dtm" multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
          <typeMatch typeName="coordinate"         type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Data.Coordinate, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Data" fieldNameFormat="{0}_rpt"                      settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
        </typeMatches>

        <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
          <field fieldName="__created_by"         returnType="string" />
          <field fieldName="__smallcreateddate"   returnType="datetime" format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH\:mm\:ss'Z'" />
          <field fieldName="__smallupdateddate"   returnType="datetime" format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH\:mm\:ss'Z'" />
          <field fieldName="__workflow_state"     returnType="string" />
          <field fieldName="extension"            returnType="text" />
          <field fieldName="title"                returnType="text" />
          <field fieldName="type"                 returnType="text" />
        </fieldNames>
        <fieldTypes hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldTypeName">
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="checkbox"                                                                                                 returnType="bool"             />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="date|datetime"                                                                                            returnType="datetime"         />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="html|rich text|single-line text|multi-line text|text|memo|image|reference"                                returnType="text"             />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="word document"                                                                                            returnType="text"             />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="integer"                                                                                                  returnType="long"             />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="number"                                                                                                   returnType="float"            />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="icon|droplist|grouped droplist"                                                                           returnType="string"           />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="checklist|multilist|treelist|tree list|treelistex|tree list|multilist with search|treelist with search"   returnType="stringCollection" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="name lookup value list|name value list"                                                                   returnType="stringCollection" />
          <fieldType fieldTypeName="droplink|droptree|grouped droplink|tree"                                                                  returnType="stringCollection" />
        </fieldTypes>
      </fieldMap>

      <documentOptions type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilderOptions, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
        <indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields>

        <exclude hint="list:AddExcludedTemplate">
          <BucketFolderTemplateId>{ADB6CA4F-03EF-4F47-B9AC-9CE2BA53FF97}</BucketFolderTemplateId>
        </exclude>
       <checkTemplateInheritance>true</checkTemplateInheritance>

        <exclude hint="list:AddExcludedField">

        </exclude>
        <fields hint="raw:AddExcludedSpecialField">
          <remove type="both">AllTemplates</remove>
          <remove type="both">Created</remove>
          <remove type="both">Editor</remove>
          <remove type="both">Hidden</remove>
          <remove type="both">Icon</remove>
          <remove type="both">Links</remove>
          <remove type="both">Updated</remove>
        </fields>
        <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
          <field fieldName="__smallcreateddate"             returnType="string"          >Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.CreatedDate,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
          <field fieldName="__smallupdateddate"             returnType="string"          >Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.UpdatedDate,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
          <field fieldName="_content"                       returnType="string"     type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MediaItemContentExtractor,Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <mediaIndexing ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/mediaIndexing"/>
          </field>
          <field fieldName="calculateddimension"            returnType="stringCollection">Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.CalculatedDimension,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
          <field fieldName="culture"                        returnType="string"          >Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.Culture,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
          <field fieldName="haschildren"                    returnType="bool"            >Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.HasChildren,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
          <field fieldName="istemplate"                     returnType="bool"            >Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.IsTemplate,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
          <field fieldName="lock"                           returnType="bool"            >Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.IsLocked,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
          <field fieldName="parsedcreatedby"                returnType="string"          >Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.ParsedCreatedBy,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
          <field fieldName="parsedupdatedby"                returnType="string"          >Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.ParsedUpdatedBy,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
          <field fieldName="parsedlanguage"                 returnType="string"          >Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.ParsedLanguage,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
          <field fieldName="site"                           returnType="stringCollection">Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.Site,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
          <field fieldName="sizerange"                      returnType="string"          >Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.FileSizeGrouping,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
          <field fieldName="version"                        returnType="intCollection"   >Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.StoreVersionTermVector,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
          <field fieldName="isbucket_text"                  returnType="string"          >Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.IsBucket,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
          <field fieldName="__lock"                         returnType="string"          >Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.ParsedLockOwner,Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
          <field fieldName="ispointofinterest"              returnType="bool"            >Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.IsPointOfInterest, Sitecore.ContentSearch</field>
          <field fieldName="coordinate"                     returnType="coordinate"      >Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.ComputedFields.Coordinate, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider</field>
          <field fieldName="__solr_norm_field_name"         returnType="string"          >Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.FieldNames.TypeResolving.Index.ComputedFields.NormalizedTemplateFieldName,Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider</field>
          <field fieldName="__solr_field_type"              returnType="string"          >Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.FieldNames.TypeResolving.Index.ComputedFields.TemplateFieldType,Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider</field>
        </fields>
      </documentOptions>
  <mediaIndexing hint="skip">
        <mimeTypes>
          <excludes>
            <mimeType>*</mimeType>
          </excludes>
          <includes>
            <mimeType>application/pdf</mimeType>
            <mimeType type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MediaItemHtmlTextExtractor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">text/html</mimeType>
            <mimeType>text/plain</mimeType>
          </includes>
        </mimeTypes>
        <extensions>
          <excludes>
            <extension>*</extension>
          </excludes>
          <includes>
            <extension>rtf</extension>
            <extension>odt</extension>
            <extension>doc</extension>
            <extension>dot</extension>
            <extension>docx</extension>
            <extension>dotx</extension>
            <extension>docm</extension>
            <extension>dotm</extension>
            <extension>xls</extension>
            <extension>xlt</extension>
            <extension>xla</extension>
            <extension>xlsx</extension>
            <extension>xlsm</extension>
            <extension>xltm</extension>
            <extension>xlam</extension>
            <extension>xlsb</extension>
            <extension>ppt</extension>
            <extension>pot</extension>
            <extension>pps</extension>
            <extension>ppa</extension>
            <extension>pptx</extension>
            <extension>potx</extension>
            <extension>ppsx</extension>
            <extension>ppam</extension>
            <extension>pptm</extension>
            <extension>potm</extension>
            <extension>ppsm</extension>
          </includes>
        </extensions>
      </mediaIndexing>
      <virtualFields type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.VirtualFieldProcessorMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <processors hint="raw:AddFromConfiguration">
          <add fieldName="daterange" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.VirtualFields.DateRangeFieldProcessor, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <add fieldName="_lastestversion" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.VirtualFields.LatestVersionFieldProcessor, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <add fieldName="updateddaterange" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.VirtualFields.UpdatedDateRangeFieldProcessor, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <add fieldName="_url" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.VirtualFields.UniqueIdFieldProcessor, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <add fieldName="_fullpath" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.VirtualFields.FullPathFieldProcessor, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
          <add fieldName="parsedcreatedby_s" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.VirtualFields.CreatedByFieldProcessor, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        </processors>
      </virtualFields>

<mapFieldByFieldName hint="raw:AddFieldReaderByFieldName">
 <fieldReader fieldName="perkTermsConditions" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.DefaultFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
 </mapFieldByFieldName>
      <fieldReaders type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.FieldReaderMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <param desc="id">defaultFieldReaderMap</param>
        <mapFieldByTypeName hint="raw:AddFieldReaderByFieldTypeName">
          <fieldReader fieldTypeName="checkbox"                                             fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.CheckboxFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <fieldReader fieldTypeName="date|datetime"                                        fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.DateFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <fieldReader fieldTypeName="image"                                                fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.ImageFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <fieldReader fieldTypeName="single-line text|multi-line text|text|memo"           fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.DefaultFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <fieldReader fieldTypeName="integer"                                              fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.NumericFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <fieldReader fieldTypeName="number"                                               fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.PrecisionNumericFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <fieldReader fieldTypeName="html|rich text"                                       fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.RichTextFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <fieldReader fieldTypeName="multilist with search|treelist with search"           fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.DelimitedListFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <fieldReader fieldTypeName="checklist|multilist|treelist|treelistex|tree list"    fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.MultiListFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <fieldReader fieldTypeName="icon|droplist|grouped droplist"                       fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.DefaultFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <fieldReader fieldTypeName="name lookup value list|name value list"               fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.NameValueListFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <fieldReader fieldTypeName="droplink|droptree|grouped droplink|tree|reference"    fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.LookupFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <fieldReader fieldTypeName="attachment|frame|rules|tracking|thumbnail"            fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.NullFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <fieldReader fieldTypeName="file|security|server file|template field source|link" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.NullFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        </mapFieldByTypeName>
      </fieldReaders>

      <indexFieldStorageValueFormatter type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Converters.SolrIndexFieldStorageValueFormatter, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
        <converters hint="raw:AddConverter">
          <converter handlesType="System.Guid"                                                          typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldGuidValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <converter handlesType="Sitecore.Data.ID, Sitecore.Kernel"                                    typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldIDValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <converter handlesType="Sitecore.Data.ShortID, Sitecore.Kernel"                               typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldShortIDValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <converter handlesType="System.DateTime"                                                      typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldUTCDateTimeValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <converter handlesType="System.DateTimeOffset"                                                typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldDateTimeOffsetValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <converter handlesType="System.TimeSpan"                                                      typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldTimeSpanValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <converter handlesType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemId, Sitecore.ContentSearch"        typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldSitecoreItemIDValueConvertor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <param type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldIDValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch"/>
          </converter>
          <converter handlesType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemUniqueId, Sitecore.ContentSearch"  typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Converters.SolrIndexFieldSitecoreItemUniqueIDValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
            <param type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldItemUriValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch"/>
          </converter>
          <converter handlesType="Sitecore.Data.ItemUri, Sitecore.Kernel"                               typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldItemUriValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <converter handlesType="Sitecore.Globalization.Language, Sitecore.Kernel"                     typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldLanguageValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <converter handlesType="System.Globalization.CultureInfo"                                     typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldCultureInfoValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <converter handlesType="Sitecore.Data.Version, Sitecore.Kernel"                               typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldVersionValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <converter handlesType="Sitecore.Data.Database, Sitecore.Kernel"                              typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldDatabaseValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <converter handlesType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.IIndexableId, Sitecore.ContentSearch"          typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexableIdConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <converter handlesType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.IIndexableUniqueId, Sitecore.ContentSearch"    typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexableUniqueIdConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          <converter handlesType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Data.Coordinate, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Data"  typeConverter="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Converters.IndexFieldCoordinateValueConverter, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        </converters>
      </indexFieldStorageValueFormatter>
      <indexDocumentPropertyMapper type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Mapping.SolrDocumentPropertyMapper, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
        <objectFactory type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.DefaultDocumentMapperObjectFactory, Sitecore.ContentSearch">

        </objectFactory>
      </indexDocumentPropertyMapper>

      <documentBuilderType>Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilder, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider</documentBuilderType>

      <defaultSearchSecurityOption ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSearchSecurityOption" />

    </defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
```

Comment: Can you paste the whole content of your patch file?

Comment: @MarekMusielak: Right now I am just doing the POC before actually incorporating that. So, I have just pasted it below 'SITECORE FIELDTYPE MAP' at same hirearchy.

Comment: Can you copy the content of the whole parent node then?

Comment: @MarekMusielak: Done. Had to remove a few items from "AddExcludedField" to trim the content.

Comment: See the answer from @Gatogordo - that's exactly how it should be configured. It looks like you added the config part in wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `<mapFieldByFieldName hint="raw:AddFieldReaderByFieldName">` needs to be inside the `<fieldReaders type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.FieldReaderMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">...</fieldReaders>` section.

Result of that section would be:

```
<fieldReaders type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.FieldReaderMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
    <param desc="id">defaultFieldReaderMap</param>
    <mapFieldByTypeName hint="raw:AddFieldReaderByFieldTypeName">
        <fieldReader fieldTypeName="checkbox"                                             fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.CheckboxFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        <fieldReader fieldTypeName="date|datetime"                                        fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.DateFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        <fieldReader fieldTypeName="image"                                                fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.ImageFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        <fieldReader fieldTypeName="single-line text|multi-line text|text|memo"           fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.DefaultFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        <fieldReader fieldTypeName="integer"                                              fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.NumericFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        <fieldReader fieldTypeName="number"                                               fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.PrecisionNumericFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        <fieldReader fieldTypeName="html|rich text"                                       fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.RichTextFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        <fieldReader fieldTypeName="multilist with search|treelist with search"           fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.DelimitedListFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        <fieldReader fieldTypeName="checklist|multilist|treelist|treelistex|tree list"    fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.MultiListFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        <fieldReader fieldTypeName="icon|droplist|grouped droplist"                       fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.DefaultFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        <fieldReader fieldTypeName="name lookup value list|name value list"               fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.NameValueListFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        <fieldReader fieldTypeName="droplink|droptree|grouped droplink|tree|reference"    fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.LookupFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        <fieldReader fieldTypeName="attachment|frame|rules|tracking|thumbnail"            fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.NullFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        <fieldReader fieldTypeName="file|security|server file|template field source|link" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.NullFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
    </mapFieldByTypeName>
    <mapFieldByFieldName hint="raw:AddFieldReaderByFieldName">
      <fieldReader fieldName="perkTermsConditions" fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.DefaultFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
    </mapFieldByFieldName>
</fieldReaders>
```